# Updating/Creating a column by adding previous row values from another column based on conditions

Tags: sqlite

I'm setting up a table in a SQLite Database that needs to have a column that sums up values based on another column's condition.

```
 Table 
 Index     Event    Hours At Location     Total Hours

  1        In       0                     --
  2        Out      10                    --
  3        In       0                     --
  4        Out      5                     --
  5        In       0                     --
  6        Checkup  3                     --
  7        Out      5                     --
```

The Index column just keeps track of the events chronologically, think of it as a timestamp. There are only 3 types of Events (In, Checkup, Out). I would like to sum up the total hours based on these events. Information that will be inserted into the table only consists of ID, Event, Hours At Location.

Analogy: When a person goes into the place, hours at location is 0, total hours is 0. Then the person comes out after 10 hours which is kept track with hours at location, then the total hours would update to 10. However, sometimes you just check on the person but the person has not left yet. So the total hours should only add the hours at location so far at the time of check-up. But when the person comes out, the total hours should not add both the length of time at check up and after coming out.

```
 Table 
 Index     Event    Hours At Location   Total Hours

  1        In       0                   0
  2        Out      10                  10 
  3        In       0                   10
  4        Out      5                   15
  5        In       0                   15
  6        Checkup  3                   18 
  7        Out      5                   20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With modern versions of sqlite (3.25 and newer), you can use window functions to compute a running sum:

```
SELECT id, event, hours
     , sum(hours) FILTER (WHERE event <> 'Checkup') OVER (ORDER BY id)
       + CASE event WHEN 'Checkup' THEN hours ELSE 0 END AS "Total Hours"
FROM tracker
ORDER BY id;
```

```
id          event       hours       Total Hours
----------  ----------  ----------  -----------
1           In          0           0
2           Out         10          10
3           In          0           10
4           Out         5           15
5           In          0           15
6           Checkup     3           18
7           Out         5           20
```

The trick here is computing the running total of all non-checkup entries by weeding them out with a filter, and then if the current entry is a checkup, adding its hours to the total just for that row.

Answer (score 0):

You need conditional aggregation in the update statement:

```
update tablename
set totalhours = (
  select 
    sum(case 
      when event = 'Checkup' and t.`index` < tablename.`index` then 0 
      else hoursatlocation 
     end) 
  from tablename t
  where t.`index` <= tablename.`index`
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/neqvWyMNTy9ZwJitzKqTok/0).
Results:

```
| Index | Event   | HoursAtLocation | TotalHours |
| ----- | ------- | --------------- | ---------- |
| 1     | In      | 0               | 0          |
| 2     | Out     | 10              | 10         |
| 3     | In      | 0               | 10         |
| 4     | Out     | 5               | 15         |
| 5     | In      | 0               | 15         |
| 6     | Checkup | 3               | 18         |
| 7     | Out     | 5               | 20         |
```